# Getting separate values from separate rows using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, case-when

I have a dataset where users have 2 actions, a useful action and a non-useful action:

```
user_id | action_id | useful
   1    |     3     |  True
   1    |     4     |  False
   2    |     5     |  True
```

I'd like a dataset which shows the user id, and the ids of the useful and non-useful actions they took on the same row. Like this:

```
user_id | useful_action_id | not_useful_action_id
   1    |       3          |         4
   2    |       5          |       NULL
```

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    case when useful = True then action_id else null end,
    case when useful = False then action_id else null end
FROM actions
GROUP BY user_id
```

But I'm told that:

```
Error running query: column "useful" must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

But no, I specifically don't want 'useful' to appear in the `GROUP BY` right? I just want it to be grouped by `user_id`

Comment: This may help [How to Pivot in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135079/how-to-pivot-in-postgresql)

Comment: @CuriousKid - `crosstab()` is overkill for this scenario, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `GROUP BY`, but performing no aggregation. It looks like you are attempting a conditional aggregation and you are very close. You simply need to use an aggregate function, like so:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    max(case when useful = True then action_id end) AS useful_action_id,
    max(case when useful = False then action_id end) AS not_useful_action_id
FROM actions
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: OK! Even if the aggregate function is totally useless? In this case there is only one possible useful and one possible not-useful

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Yep - that is correct. The alternative is to do a pivot on the data, but this is generally the easier alternative to that.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Using `array_agg()` instead of `max()` could to solve the problem.

Comment: @Nicarus `max(action_id) filter (where useful | not useful)` IMO more readable.

Comment: @Abelisto - Sure there are a lot of ways to do the same thing. And depending on which version OP is running FILTER may not be supported.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have "useful" and "not useful" IDs for each user, use `array_agg()` aggregate function:

```
select
    user_id,
    array_agg(action_id) filter (where useful) as useful_action_ids,
    array_agg(action_id) filter (where not useful) as not_useful_action_ids
from actions
group by 1;
```

Couple of additional comments:

- if no IDs are found in a group, it will ouput empty array (`{}`), not NULL. If you do need NULLs, add case/when expressions.
- if you have NULLs in the `useful` column, they will not be taken by the query above. In this case, if you do want such NULLs to be considered as a "not useful", just use `(where not coalesce(useful, false))`. But probably you'll prefer having one more set of IDs, say, `usefulness_is_not_clear` with `filter (where useful is null)` :)

Comment: Worth it to note that FILTER is only available in 9.4+

Comment: ...and is a part of SQL:2003 standard ;)

Comment: No argument here, it's just good to be clear and specific to the RDMS that is used. Not all implement every SQL  standard feature at the same time and most users will know the version, but not the date it was released.

Comment: You sound like having a bag of arguments :))

Comment: I have no idea what that means, sorry.

Comment: Let's better return to the main question. Author asked: "I'd like a dataset which shows the user id, and the ids, ...". Your query is a significantly different. Let's do this: edit your answer making it giving the answer the author needed and I'll remove mine.

Comment: You can do it w/o `filter`, btw ;)

Comment: If you think my answer is incorrect, please feel free to downvote it. It appears from OP's comments that it has met the need, so I'm not under the impression it is wrong.

Comment: You're obviously only interested in trolling, so I'll end it here. Have a good day.

Comment: It's not a trolling, it's a wish to be clear and make correct answers. SO is top SEOed website for developers and people might find this question in the future, so giving correct answers is the primary goal of SO's community.

Comment: Thanks for this :) I'll look into filter too. Sorry Nicarus got there first with a correct answer so I have to accept him, but this is really nice too.